# python solving differential equation with complex variables

Tags: python, complex-numbers, differential-equations

folks,

Is it possible to solve ODE with complex variable in python? The equation I have has the following form

```
dx/dt = -a x -i y(t)
```

where y(t) is a known function, a is a known number and i is the root of -1.

I tried to use odeint() but it gives many error messages.

I am guessing odeint() does not work with complex variables. So one way out would be to separate the real and imaginary parts of x and treat the original ODE as two coupled ODEs.

But I am also wondering if there are some more convenient way for this task? Solving ODE/PDE with complex variables is a general problem and it will be quite a hassle to make this complex -> real conversion by hand all the time.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This page lists several ODE solvers: http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific.    Therefore, the answer to "is it possible" is likely "Yes."  Perhaps you should try a few of these and ask **specific** questions.

Comment: Or you could code it yourself using an algorithm like [Runge Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using `scipy.integrate.complex_ode` instead of `scipy.integrate.odeint` which [performs the conversion automatically](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.complex_ode.html).